# Document Centre in SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site

Tags: publishing-site

When I try to create a new sub site from a Publishing Site Collection, the only options I get are:

- Publishing Site
- Enterprise Wiki

I want to create a "Document Centre" site definition within this Site Collection. Any ideas how to enabled this site definition as an option to pick? This all in the context of SharePoint 2010

Cheers,
Anthony

Comment: Please clarify your question and explain where you dont see the document center?

Comment: Wictor - I've clarified the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a site using the 'Publishing Portal' template then the only sub-site you can create is Publishing Portal with Workflow.

You need to go to Site Settings > Page layouts and site templates.  In here you can optionally allow individual site templates to be used or else click on 'Sub sites can use any site template' to restore all the available site templates for use as sub-sites.